# Prettier write all files without explicitly specify supported file extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prettier

Prettier can write files without explicitly specify extensions like this:

`prettier --write '**/*.*'`

However, this command makes prettier keeps logging warning about not supporting XXX file extension.

Right now, I have to use node to achieve this:

```js
const { getSupportInfo } = require('prettier');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

const extensions = getSupportInfo()
  .languages.map(language => language.extensions)
  .flat(1);

const formattedExtensionString = extensions
  .map(ext => ext.slice(1, ext.length))
  .join(',');

execSync(
  `prettier --write '**/*.{${formattedExtensionString}}'`,
  {
    stdio: 'inherit'
  }
);
```

Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`prettier --write .` is supported since Prettier 2.0. See the [release notes](https://prettier.io/blog/2020/03/21/2.0.0.html#expand-directories-including--7660httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull7660-by-thorn0httpsgithubcomthorn0).